# How to update customer in braintree payment method

Tags: yii2, braintree

I have integrated braintree method in yii2 rest api [Using this reference.](https://github.com/bryglen/yii2-braintree). I want to update the customer but I am getting following error:

> Missing argument 2 for Braintree\Customer::update()

Below is my code :

```
 $braintree = Yii::$app->braintree;
       $response = $braintree->call('Customer', 'update','15552090',[                               

                                      'firstName' => 'test-1545',
                                      'lastName' => 'asdf',
                                      'company' => 'New Company',
                                      'email' => 'new.email@example.com',
                                      'phone' => 'new phone',
                                      'fax' => 'new fax',
                                      'website' => 'http://new.example.com'

                            ]);
                        print_r($response); die;
```

I am stack here how to pass the arguments?

Comment: Please provide reference to extensions you are using.

Comment: I am using following https://github.com/bryglen/yii2-braintree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a problem of this particular extension. See [this issue](https://github.com/bryglen/yii2-braintree/issues/3) on Github.

Issue OP recommends this fix:

```
public function call($command, $method, $values, $values2 = null)
{
    $class = strtr("{class}_{command}", [
        '{class}' => $this->_prefix,
        '{command}' => $command,
    ));

    if ($values2) {
        return call_user_func(array($class, $method), $values, $values2);
    else {
        return call_user_func(array($class, $method), $values);
    }
}
```

while extension author recommends this:

```
if (is_array($values)) {
   call_user_func_array(...);
} else {
   call_user_func(...);
}
```

Either way you need to override this component with your own and apply a patch.

Note that the amount of code in application is small (64 lines in one file) so you can create your own wrapper or find better one because this issue is still not fixed.

And maybe is better to directly use [braintree_php](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_php) methods which will be more clear than magical `call`.

**Update:** To override component, create own class extending from bryglen's, place it for example in `common/components` folder in case of using advanced app.

```
namespace common\components;

class Braintree extends \bryglen\braintree\Braintree
{
    public function call($command, $method, $values)
    {
        // Override logic here
    }
}
```

Then replace extension class name with your custom one in config:

```
'components' => [
    'braintree' => [
        'class' => 'common\components\Braintree',
        'environment' => 'sandbox',
        'merchantId' => 'your_merchant_id',
        'publicKey' => 'your_public_key',
        'privateKey' => 'your_private_key',
    ],
],
```

Comment: Can you please guide me or provide any hints how to override this component as i am new in yii2. Thanks

Comment: @Arunendra I updated the answer with more detailed instructions on how to do that.